# What does open memcheck xml log file do?

Tags: codeblocks, valgrind

I am currently using valgrind in code::blocks on both mac and linux. Running mem check creates an xml log file. When I open the xml log file with open memcheck xml log file nothing happens. Ive looked everywhere on the software including the logs for valgrind. There is nothing. Am I doing something wrong? Is that feature currently broken? What is the feature supposed to be doing?

Comment: Don’t know about code::blocks integration, but valgrind memcheck output is also quite readable when used from the command-line, so I’d give that a try.

Comment: I've been using valgrind from the terminal to do memory checking due to the above issue but it would be so much easier to use it directly from Code::Blocks.